# Is there any Western country that didn't ban the patenting of human genes?

Tags: law, international, western-world, technology, intellectual-property

> When Finance Minister Paul Martin announced $160 million in funding
> for genome research in Canada in his Feb. 28, 2000, budget, the timing
> could not have been better. **The first human chromosome had just been
> sequenced. US President Bill Clinton and British Prime Minister Tony
> Blair were calling for a ban on patenting human genes. And the full
> genome of the fruit fly was about to be released.**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1232482/pdf/cmaj_162_10_1478.pdf

> In June 2013, the U.S. Supreme Court unanimously ruled that naturally
> occurring genes and genetic sequences are not patentable. The case
> centered on patents on the genes BRCA1 and BRCA2, which are normal
> genes found in all humans, but mutations in them increase the risk for
> breast cancer.

https://www.ama-assn.org/delivering-care/precision-medicine/gene-patenting

Is there any Western country that didn't ban the patenting of human genes? Knowing that the U.S. banned patenting on not only human genes, but all genes that are naturally occurring, I was wondering if there was any Western country that decided otherwise and are reaping benefits from allowing the patenting of human genes.

Comment: Title asks about "western"  (definion?)  Body asks about "Any country".  Last sentence could be rewritten  "I was wondering if there was any country that decided otherwise and are *suffering the consequences* of allowing the patenting of human genes"

Comment: Patent policy nowadays is harmonized internationally, that might be an angle to investigate it

Comment: The EU seems to allow some patenting of gene sequences ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_patent)) but seems to only allow novel sequences, so I'm not sure exactly what the limits are.